# Why is $\mathfrak{ N }_S$ not finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: number-theory, logic

Let $\mathfrak{ N }_S = (\mathbb{ N }; 0, S)$. With axioms ($A_S$):

1: $\forall x (Sx \neq 0)$

2: $\forall x \forall y (Sx = Sy \rightarrow x = y)$

3: $\forall y (y \neq 0 \rightarrow \exists x (y = Sx))$

4.1: $\forall x (Sx \neq x)$

4.2: $\forall x (S^2x \neq x)$

...

4.n: $\forall x (S^n x \neq x)$

Why is $\mathfrak{ N }_S$ not axiomatizable? I know that if it is finitely axiomatizable then we can find some finite $\Sigma \subseteq A_S$ such that $\mbox{Cn} \,\Sigma = \mbox{Cn} \,A_S$. I know that there is some $N > 0$ such that for $n > N$ axiom 4.n is not in $A_S$. Thus it suffices to show that axiom 4.n is not in $\mbox{Cn} \,A_S$.

I'm a bit stuck. I considered trying to construct a model but I'm stuck.

Could I have a hint?

Comment: What does Cn mean?

Comment: Consquence, i.e. Cn $A = \{ \tau \mid A \vDash \tau \}$.

Comment: In order to prove it, I think it is enough to show that if we "cut" the axiom-set to a finite $N$, then the resulting theory has a finite model. Following Enderton's suggestion [**Ex.6**, page 193 : Show that Th $\mathfrak N_S$ is not finitely axiomatizable. Suggestion: Show that no finite subset of $A_S$ suffices, and then apply Sect.2.6.] we can use the argument of page 156 : "that finite subset would be true in some [domain] of very large [cardinality]".

Answer (score 1):

I do not have Enderton's book, so I don't know the argument that Mauro is referring to. So I will prove that there is no finite subset of $A_{S}$ that axiomatizes the given structure.

In order to show this, it suffices to show that any finite subset of $A_{S}$ has a non-standard interpretation in $\mathfrak{N}_{S}$. So let $T_{0}\subseteq{A_{S}}$ be finite. The interesting case is when axiom 1,2,3 and some of the $4.n$ axioms are in $T_{0}$. So assume that this is the case. Let $N$ be the max of the indexes of the axioms of the form $4.{n}$ inside of $T_{0}$.

Interpret $S$ as follows:  $S(x)=(k+1)N$ if $x=kN$, and $S(x)=x+1$ otherwise. You can easily verify that the axioms hold under this interpretation. So the result we want follows.